# ApolloGraphQL not triggering query when landing on page after a mutation that changes data

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

**Intended result**

I have two routes: `/test/` and `/test/:id`.

On `/test/` I have a list of `events` and it's only made of events that haven't been `resolved`

On `/test/:id` I have a `mutation` to mark an `event` as `resolved`, and, on success, I'm redirecting the user back to `/test/`.
This success means that the `event` should no longer appear on `/test/` and I'm expecting a new request to get the list of `events`.

```js
// my file with the mutation
  const [eventResolveMutation] = useEventResolveMutation({
    onCompleted: () => {
      showSuccessToast(
        `${t('form:threat-resolved')}! ${t('general:threat')} ${t(
          'form:has-been-resolved'
        )}.`
      )

      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate('/threats/live')
      }, 2000)
    },
    onError: (error: ApolloError) => {
      showErrorToast(error.message)
    },
  })

  const handleEventResolveClick = (id: string) => {
    eventResolveMutation({ variables: { id: id, isResolved: true } })
  }

return (
  <button onClick={() => handleEventResolveClick(id)}>Press</button>
)
```

```js
// my file with the `events` query
// the results are displayed in a table, which is way I have `currentPage` and `pageSize` in them

  const [getEvents, { loading, data }] = useEventsLazyQuery()

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents({
      variables: {
        page: currentPage,
        pageSize: paginationSizeOptions[chosenDropdownIndex],
        isThreat: true,
        isResolved: false,
      },
    })
  }, [chosenDropdownIndex, currentPage, getEvents])
```

**Actual outcome:**

Once I press the `button` that triggers the mutation and I'm redirected to the `/tests`, I can see that I'm landing inside the `useEffect` by `logging` something. What I don't see is a request made via `getEvents`, which is expected to happen since all the functionalities with the page work

**Extra info:**

```js
// my graphqlclient.ts

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client'

const serverUrl = () => {
  switch (process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'staging':
      return 'env'

    case 'production':
      return 'env'

    default:
      return 'env'
  }
}

const cleanTypeName = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  if (operation.variables) {
    const omitTypename = (key: string, value: any) =>
      key === '__typename' ? undefined : value

    operation.variables = JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(operation.variables),
      omitTypename
    )
  }

  return forward(operation).map((data) => data)
})

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: serverUrl(),
  credentials: 'include',
})

const httpLinkWithTypenameHandling = ApolloLink.from([cleanTypeName, httpLink])

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLinkWithTypenameHandling,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    },
  },
})

export default client
```

```js
// my mutation
// this mutation will mark an `id` as `resolved` and that means that it should disappear from the list above

mutation EventResolve($id: ID!, $isResolved: Boolean!) {
  eventResolve(id: $id, isResolved: $isResolved) {
    id
    sequence
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you expect a request to happen, the data is still in the `InMemoryCache`?

Comment: If the data is changing, shouldn't `cache` be ignored? Because one of the properties of one of the objects just changed

Comment: You haven't shown the queries, but Apollo doesn't know what else changed. If a property of the object changed, and the mutation returns that new data with the same id, the cache will automatically update and the query will return the new data without needing to make a request. But the list of events won't change.

Comment: I've added my mutation to the post but I'm marking with it an `id` with `isResolved: true`. If my query is only getting data that is marked with `isResolved: false`, I'm expecting it to do a new request since one of the objects within the data changed and is no longer valid

Comment: What does the query look like? And no, Apollo doesn't magically know how your API does apply the `isResolved: false` filter.